# How to find the time interval from 'unicode' and 'datetime.datetime' formats

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code snippet where i need to find the interval in minutes.
How can i find the difference in time on these two variables which are in different formats. How can i get the elapsed time in minutes from these? Thanks.

```
eventTimestamp= u'2018-01-22T08:00:05.579Z',
endtimestamp = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 22, 8, 0, 7, 197000, tzinfo=tzutc())
completition_time = endtimestamp - eventTimestamp

#Converting interval into minutes
secnds = completition_time.total_seconds()
minutes = int(secnds / 60)

if( (minutes >= 30) ):
    print("MATCH FOUND")
```

If i run this i get the following error, at line 3 :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Where do `finish_tmstmp` and `event_tmstmp` come from?

Comment: sorry for the error, i corrected

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subtract datetime object and string object. You need to convert the string to datetime

```
import datetime

eventTimestamp= datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-22T08:00:05.579Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the unicode string into datetime object to use the `-` minus sign operator

```
import datetime

unicode_timestamp= u'2018-01-22T08:00:05.579Z'
datetime_from_unicode = datetime.datetime.strptime(unicode_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior for formatting if your unicode is different